# Given an item, how can I count the occurrences of said item in a list, and not print the item if it does not reach certain regulations?

Tags: python, list

Say you have a list, and you want each item in the list to have two "a"'s, regardless of case, and two "g"'s, also regardless of case. How would you stop python from printing "aaGa", aGGG", etc., but print all the other items that *do* have two "a"'s and "g"'s?

Update:
Here's an example of what is currently being printed:

```
['aAaA', 'aAaG', 'aAAG', 'aAGG', 'aAaA', 'aAag', 'aAAG', 'aAGg', 'aAaa', 'aAaG', 'aAaG', 'aAGG', 'aAaa', 'aAag', 'aAaG', 'aAGg', 'aAaA', 'aAaG', 'aAAG', 'aAGG', 'aAaA', 'aAag', 'aAAG', 'aAGg', 'aAaa', 'aAaG', 'aAaG', 'aAGG', 'aAaa', 'aAag', 'aAaG', 'aAGg', 'aAaA', 'aAaG', 'aAAG', 'aAGG', 'aAaA', 'aAag', 'aAAG', 'aAGg', 'aAaa', 'aAaG', 'aAaG', 'aAGG', 'aAaa', 'aAag', 'aAaG', 'aAGg', 'aAaA']
```

And here's an example of what it *should* look like:

```
['aaGG', 'Aagg', 'AAGG', 'AaGG', 'aaGg', 'AAGg', 'AAgg', etc.]
```

Comment: an example along with expected output would be better.

Comment: There you go @AvinashRaj

Comment: are you trying to do an exact count? Did you want to match this `aaGGg'?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
word_list = ["AAgg", "aGGG", "AgaG", "gAaA"]
for idx in word_list:
    if idx.lower().count("a") == idx.lower().count("g") == 2:
        print idx
```

**EDIT**

If you want your results back as a list like in your edit just put it all in one line

`print [idx for idx in word_list if idx.lower().count("a") == idx.lower().count("g") == 2]`

Comment: You could chain the equality by removing `2 and` (for the form `a==b==c`).

Comment: You're right, edited the answer. thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Thanks so much Dor-Ron and @TigerhawkT3  Both your answers were very helpful

Comment: I do have one more question though: When I print it, it prints probably 50x. Why is this? And what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: You mean when you print it's slower?

Comment: Not necessarily slower. It print the same thing infinitely. I may have done something that caused it to be an infinite loop, but I didn't really change anything

Comment: It prints that many times because there were that many matches. If you want certain restrictions on the output, you'll have to specify them.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @TigerhawkT3

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex. This would print all the items in the list which has atleast 2 `g`'s and 2 `a`'s.

```
[i for i in lst if re.search(r'(?i)^(?=.*?a.*?a)(?=.*?g.*?g)', i)]
```

Example:

```
>>> lst = ["aaGa", "aGGG", 'aagg', 'gagar', 'Gttgata', 'GGGa', 'Agaa']
>>> [i for i in lst if re.search(r'(?i)^(?=.*?a.*?a)(?=.*?g.*?g)', i)]
['aagg', 'gagar', 'Gttgata']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print [i for i in test_list if re.findall(r"^(?=.*a.*a)(?=.*g.*g).*$",i)]
```

You can use `re` module here